# Implicit conversion for matching overloads C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem understanding how function overloading works, it boils down to this simple example:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void bar(const bool & val) {} 
};

void DoFn(std::function<void( Foo*, const wxString&)> fn ) {}
```

if I now call DoFn like so:

```
DoFn( &Foo::bar );
```

it compiles fine. How is it converting from bool to wxString within the template parameter for std::function? If I change wxString to std::string then it fails to compile as expected.

(wxString is a class in wxWidgets, version 2.8)

What I really don't understand is how the wxString class is able to declare it can be converted to from a bool.

I have tried making a class as follows:

```
class FakeString {
 public:
  FakeString(bool) {};
  FakeString(const bool &){};
};
```

and replacing wxString in DoFn with FakeString, but it doesn't compile saying:

```
could not convert '&Foo::bar' from 'void (Foo::*)(const bool&)' to 'std::function<void(Foo*, const FakeString&)>'
```

Comment: Can you provide your actual working code? Are you absolutely sure there's no other `bar` version that takes a `wxString` that you've missed?

Comment: I compiled this code

Comment: Well it couldn't literally be this code as its missing `#include <wxString>`. Are you saying that's the only difference?

Comment: Yes, that seemed unnecessary for the actual question. Though I typed the FakeString bit directly into stackoverflow as I had lost it on the clipboard.

Answer (score 6):

You got the conversion order wrong: It's about converting `wxStrging` to `bool`, not in the other direction.

```
class FakeString {
 public:
  operator bool() const { return false;  }
};
```

wxString has no bool conversion operator, but something similar: an implicit conversion to `const char*`:

```
class FakeString {
 public:
  operator const char*() const { return nullptr;  }
};
```

> If you built wxWidgets with wxUSE_STL set to 1, the implicit
>   conversions to both narrow and wide C strings are disabled and
>   replaced with implicit conversions to std::string and std::wstring.

And [these](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/string.h#L1514) are the wxString methods you are looking for, the pointer conversion operators.

Comment: The `DoFn` is called with `&Foo::bar`, which is `void (Foo::*)(const bool&)`, which is need to be casted to `std::function<void(Foo*, const wxString&)>`, so `const bool&` needs to be casted to `const wxString&`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Anton `std::function` does type erasure and is based on valid usage, not signature. So as long as the function is callable with `Foo*` and `const wxString&`, it's okay.

Comment: However, I'm not seeing the implicit bool conversion operator; the one linked to is `operator!`. Maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: Ok I guess that kind of makes sense. How is std::function able to get this type of behaviour?

Comment: You are right,it isn't a bool conversion operator, but a const char*.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some confusion around the syntax of `std::function`. Is there any reason why you don't simply do

```
struct Foo {
  void bar(const bool & val) {} 
};

void DoFn(std::function<void(const bool&)> fn ) {}
```

and then

```
Foo foo = Foo();
DoFn(&foo::bar);
```

What you declare is a function taking a `Foo*` and a `WxString` argument. I don't think this is what you want. Unlike in languages like Python, in c++ you can't explicitly pass the `this` pointer. The syntax for a non-static member function pointer returning `void` would be `void(Foo::*)(const bool&)`. My guess is that the complier doesn't complain because a function with the correct signature is in scope by chance.

Comment: You can pass the this explicitly. In the DoFn in my question, you could call fn(Foo(), wxString()) and it would be correct

Comment: Well, `fn(Foo(), wxString())` is a function taking a `Foo` and a `wxString` (or cons refs thereof). This is not the `this` pointer. `this` inside `Foo::bar` is of type `*Foo`. I think you're confusing things.

Comment: Sorry I posted that comment quickly, my point was you can take a reference to a member function and invoke it with any pointer that is of the correct type. off the top of my head it could be `Foo f; wxString s; fn(&f, s);`

Comment: Agreed. What I was getting at is that `&Foo::bar` is of type `void(Foo::*)(const bool&)` and not `void( Foo*, const wxString&)`. So your issue is not the conversion from `wxString` to `bool`.